# Tengo dos tablas que contienen el mismo campo, cómo se hace cuando inserto el numero de ID

Tags: base-de-datos

tengo una duda.

Tengo dos tablas que contienen el mismo campo, cómo se hace cuando inserto el numero de ID_PERSONA en la tabla PERSONAS y al mismo tiempo en la tabla REGISTRO también contiene el mismo ID.

TABLA PERSONAS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

TABLA REGISTRO

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!!!

Comment: pues son solo dos insert... uno para la tabla personas.. y otro para la tabla registros..

Comment: Que Base de Datos usas? Por ejemplo, en Oracle existe un objeto SECUENCIA, por lo que podrías usar una secuencia PERSONA y preparar tus dos inserts con el mismo valor.

Comment: si es una dependencia de clave foranea, no podría existir el Id_persona en la tabla registro, si previamente no fue insertado en la tabla personas

Comment: cada tabla es independiente? o trabajan en conjunto?
si son independientes no debieran causarte problema alguno (un insert para cada una), ahora si ambas trabajan en conjunto y ambas son llaves deberían relacionarse entre si con ese dato, pero explícanos un poco mas!

Comment: Son 2 tablas diferentes, pero las dos tablas tienen el mismo campo. Pero ID_PERSONA de la TABLA PERSONAS es la llave primaria y en la TABLA REGISTRO la llave primaria seria ID_REG. Lo que necesito es cuando el ID_PERSONA de la TABLA PERSONAS se inserta un ID y que el ID_PERSONA de la TABLA REGISTRO también tiene el mismo numero ID de la TABLA PERSONAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar un incremental para el campo ID_PERSONA en la tabla personas, luego podrías crear un trigger para que cada que insertes una persona nueva a la tabla se inserte en la otra.
Tambien puedes hacer dos inserts en tu webservice.

Podrías intentar algo así:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER persona_registro_insert
AFTER INSERT
   ON personas
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   -- declaración de variables

BEGIN
   -- código trigger
   INSERT INTO registro
   ( id_persona )
   VALUES
   ( :new.id_persona );

EXCEPTION
   WHEN ...
   -- Manejo de errores

END;

/
```